# Calculating the amount of static charge on an object in an electric field

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose a dielectric object is in an electric field. If the strength of the field is known, and the surface area and permittivity of the object are known, can the size of the static charge on the object be calculated?

I have seen the formula $\mathbf{D} = ε\mathbf{E}$, where electric flux density ($\mathbf{D}$) is the permittivity multiplied by the strength of the electric field. Flux density is measured in coulombs per meter squared. Does this mean, if I calculate the flux density on the object using this formula, I can figure the total charge simply by multiplying the flux density by the area of the object in square meters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface charge density induced on a dielectric, at a point on the surface, is $\vec{P} \cdot \hat{n}$, where $\vec{P}$ is the polarization density and $\hat{n}$ is the vector normal to the surface at the point.  You can integrate over your surface to obtain the total charge.

Of course, you need $\vec{P}$.  If the dielectric is "nice" then you have (I think) $\vec{P}=\epsilon_0 (\epsilon_r-1)\vec{E}$, where $\epsilon_r$ is what you have called $\epsilon$ above.  If the dielectric is not nice then the Wikipedia articles on [electric susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility) and [polarization density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density) show how the mathematics will get harder.

Comment: You might want to make your links a little better.

Comment: Thanks. What is meant by a "nice" dielectric?

Comment: @joe_deniable: to quote the Wikipedia article, "homogeneous, linear, non-dispersive and isotropic".  Homogeneous means the dielectric constant is the same throughout the material.  Isotropic means the polarisation is always parallel to the applied electric field.  Non-dispersive means the polarisation is the same for all frequencies of incident electric field.  Linear means $\vec{P}\propto\vec{E}$.